# Connecting to on prem SMB share via Azure On Premise Data Gateway

Tags: azure-logic-apps, samba, powerbi-datagateway

I am researching on porting some on-prem integration workloads over to Azure. The primary tools for me are the Azure [On Premise Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-onprem) (OPDG) and Azure Logic Apps.

Most of the integrations involve dealing with on prem SMB file shares. I am trying to use the OPDG gateway with [File Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/filesystem/) for this. However I can't seem to get it to work. The OPDG docs suggest that it can only work with Windows File System. However my understanding is that SMB allows you to treat a linux share as a Windows one. (Eg: I do connect to these with .Net using Domain accounts without an issue)

Will be highly appreciative if someone can help me verify (Either official docs or personal experience) the status of SMB share connectivity with OPDG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue not related to OPDG. The server where the OPDG was installed had another level of security preventing it from accessing the SMB share. (I didn't have access to that server).

When I tried a vanilla installation of standard OPDG on my local machine, the SMB shares worked without an issue. I could both read/write files as per the security privileges of the account I used for the File Connector.